# .NET Core: how to exclude NuGet libs from output

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a project with Protobuf files that uses the simple server of Grpc.Core, not the ASP.NET Core Kestrel of IIS server. To compile the proto-files nicely with Visual Studio, you need to install the NuGet Grpc.AspNetCore in the project. However, I don't wan't them to be copied to the output directory because they are not needed. Of course I can delete them in a post-build step but that's a hack. You can mark the NuGet package as "Private Assets all" but that doesn't work. The dlls still appear in the output bin.
[image]

Does anybody know how to do the trick?

Comment: In addition, please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets). `<ExcludeAssets>Runtime</ExcludeAssets>` will prevent these assemblies being copied out to the build output directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [NuGet's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets)

- IncludeAssets

  - These assets will be consumed
- ExcludeAssets

  - These assets will not be consumed
- PrivateAssets

  - These assets will be consumed but won't flow to the parent project

so, you could try `PrivateAssets="all" ExcludeAssets="runtime"`.

Comment: ExcludeAssets="runtime" is the asnwer, thanks! In my case I had to add a dependend library further down the chain (Google.Protobuf.dll) for it to appear in the runtime but that's ok as long as I don't have a dependency on ASPNetCore since I don't use any functionality of it during runtime, only design time.